# Division rings with finitely generated group of units

Tags: gr.group-theory, ra.rings-and-algebras, division-rings

Is there any classification of division rings with finitely generated group of units? Is there any non-trivial example?

Comment: In the commutative case it's easy to check that this implies that the division ring $D$ is finite. This is more generally true when $D$ is finite-dimensional over its center (see [this MathSE answer by Jeremy Rickard](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2777777/35400), which refers to [this Proc AMS paper by S. Akbari and M. Mahdavi-Hezavehi](http://dx.doi.org/10.1090/S0002-9939-99-05182-5)). In general this seems to be conjectural.

Comment: @YCor thank you.